# Easyadmin 4 Dynamic form how does it work?

Tags: php, symfony, easyadmin

I use this config :
Symfony 6.2
EasyAdmin 4
PHP 8.1

I have these relationships:
[image]

I have these forms:

```
    <?php
namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\LigneDeCommande;
use App\Entity\Produit;
use App\Entity\TypeProduit;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\ChoiceType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;

class LigneDeCommandeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('commande')
            ->add('quantite')
            ->add('typeProduit', EntityType::class, [
                'mapped' => false,
                'class' => TypeProduit::class,
                'placeholder' => 'Catégorie',
                'label' => 'Catégorie',
                'required' => false
            ])
            ->add('produit', ChoiceType::class, [
                'placeholder' => 'plat (choisir une catégorie)',
                'required' => false
            ])
        ;

        $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, TypeProduit $typeProduit = null) {
            $produits = null === $typeProduit ? [] : $typeProduit->getProduits();
            $form->add('produit', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Produit::class,
                'choices' => $produits,
                'required' => false,
                'choice_label' => 'nom',
                'placeholder' => 'Produit (Choisir une categorie)',
                'attr' => ['class' => 'custom-select'],
                'label' => 'Produit'
            ]);
        };

        $builder->get('typeProduit')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                $typeProduit = $event->getForm()->getData();
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $typeProduit);
            }
        );
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => LigneDeCommande::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And :

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Commande;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class CommandeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('date')
            ->add('numero')
            //->add('client')
            ->add('client', CollectionType::class, [
                    'entry_type' => SallesType::class,
                    'by_reference' => false,
                    'allow_add' => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true
            ])
            ->add('serveur')
            ->add('lignesDeCommandes', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => LigneDeCommandeType::class,
                'entry_options' => ['label' => false],
                'by_reference' => false,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Commande::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

In my CRUD controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use App\Entity\Commande;
use App\Form\SallesType;
use App\Form\TablesType;
use App\Form\CommandeType;
use App\Form\LigneDeCommandeType;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\IdField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\TextField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\CollectionField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Field\AssociationField;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\{Action, Actions, Crud};
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Config\Assets;
use EasyCorp\Bundle\EasyAdminBundle\Controller\AbstractCrudController;

class CommandeCrudController extends AbstractCrudController
{
    public static function getEntityFqcn(): string
    {
        return Commande::class;
    }

    public function configureCrud(Crud $crud): Crud
    {
        return $crud
            ->setEntityLabelInSingular('Commande')
            ->setEntityLabelInPlural('Commandes')
            ->setPageTitle("index", "Administration Commandes")
            ->setPageTitle("new", "Ajouter une Commande")
            ->setPageTitle("edit", "Modifier une Commande")
            ->showEntityActionsInlined();
    }

    public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
    {
        return $actions
            ->update(
                Crud::PAGE_INDEX,
                Action::EDIT,
                function (Action $action) {
                    return $action->setIcon('fa fa-pen fa-lg')->setLabel(false);
                }
            )
            ->update(
                Crud::PAGE_INDEX,
                Action::DELETE,
                function (Action $action) {
                    return $action->setIcon('fa fa-trash fa-lg')->setLabel(false);
                }
            );
    }

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
    {
        yield IdField::new('id')->hideOnForm()->hideOnIndex();
        yield TextField::new('numero', 'Numéro');
        yield AssociationField::new('serveur', 'Serveur');
        yield CollectionField::new('Client', 'Table')->setEntryIsComplex()->setEntryType(TablesType::class);
        yield CollectionField::new('LignesDeCommandes')->showEntryLabel()->setEntryIsComplex()->setEntryType(LigneDeCommandeType::class);
    }
}
```

When I go to newCommande, the display of products does not update after selecting the type of product. I imagine that I have to add javascript but I don't understand how to do it. Could you help me ?
THANKS